Why are Staging Ground questions not sorted correctly with the Newest / Active sorting option?
I use a custom set of tags as my homepage, but I'm seeing staging ground questions seemingly randomly inserted into my timeline. Note the following filtered by C# tag, sorted by "Newest" and yet the staging ground question appears there for no obvious reason.
Note how the Staging Ground question is from 2 hours ago, and isn't chronologically ordered like the rest. I have seen questions in this list that were asked almost 24 hours ago.


This question is similar to: Allow excluding/including/only having Staging Ground posts in a Custom filter. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

If you don't want to see Staging Ground questions, edit your profile and turn the setting to show them off.

@jonrsharpe It's not that I don't want to see them, it's that they don't fit into the timeline in chronological order. I can see questions that were asked yesterday.

I think it's done deliberately to attract reviewers, staff would probably be better to clarify that though.

This happens when using the "Active" sorting as well.

Regarding the suggested duplicate: I think there's a distinction between "I would like to include or exclude SG questions in a filter" and "why does the sorting work like this?"

@RyanM Exactly, I am happy to see them, I just don't want to see old ones.

The "Why" question is easy to answer - they are just inserted at fixed positions in the list and there may be no questions matching that timestamp (and idk how much sense it makes to consider the timestamp anyway).

@dan1st seems like that answer perfectly answers this question, I'm adding it to the dupe closure list. And just goes to show that the site making logical sense... isn't that high of a priority :/

This was a deliberate change made recently to insert Staging Ground questions in specific static positions throughout the question list and homepage.
Previously, Staging Ground questions would appear in random order on every page refresh which meant it was possible to have a number of questions grouped together which was reported in this recent Meta post and addressed.
As such, with static positions set, Staging Ground questions do not respect the sort order of the page. Different questions should be displayed on every page refresh (assuming there are enough in the New or Re-evaluate status).
I will update this post with status-bydesign .
